# Custom Alert Dialog with Multiple Views

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create a custom alert with cancel button shown in the below Picture,
Please help me to create this. Thanks in advance.!

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you tried and what specific problems you encountered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MainActivity class

```
    Button openAlert;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    openAlert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openAlert);

    openAlert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View alertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, null);

            //Set the view
            alert.setView(alertView);
            //Show alert
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.show();
            //Can not close the alert by touching outside.
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) alertView.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);

            closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });



        }
    });



}
```

MainActivity XML -> This is just a button that opens the alert

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vzw.www.multviewalert.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OPEN ALERT"
        android:id="@+id/openAlert"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to create a custom layout for the alert

custom_alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alertContainer"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_alert_bg">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/rowOne">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rowOneButtonOne"
                android:background="#cdcdcd"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rowOneButtonTwo"
                android:background="#cdcdcd"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                />

           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rowOneButtonThree"
                android:background="#cdcdcd"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                />
        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/rowTwo"
        android:layout_below="@id/rowOne">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowTwoButtonOne"
            android:background="#cdcdcd"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowTwoButtonTwo"
            android:background="#cdcdcd"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowTwoButtonThree"
            android:background="#cdcdcd"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/rowThree"
        android:layout_below="@id/rowTwo">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowThreeButtonOne"
            android:background="#cdcdcd"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowThreeButtonTwo"
            android:background="#cdcdcd"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowThreeButtonThree"
            android:background="#cdcdcd"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/closeButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:background="#cdcdcd" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the drawable for the alert background
custom_alert_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

This will produce the following

[image]

this is a skeleton.... you have to fill it in with your images and on click listeners for each.

Also, if you want to move the top section down. you can add

```
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
```

to the alertContainer ID in the custom_alert.xml

Comment: this is a skeleton.... you have to fill it in with your images and on click listeners for each

Comment: accept @Droidev answer and thank him alot he/she have done all your work infact pay him/her for that :P

Comment: @Droidev  I was looking for this --            alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
..Anyway Thanks a lot

Comment: @stephingeorge you didnt really specify that. you asked how to create that pop up. im glad you found your answer from my code though.

Comment: @Droidev You are one of the examples that there are still some good and helping developers on this website. Finally, I can ask after limitation of 4 days because I deleted my 3 downvoted questions and those questions were not unclear, off topic or had errors in them. Such a stupid decision by moderator. I lost 300 of my rep too....

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar Thanks for the words. I try to help when I can. I used to be in that same boat wondering how to do things.If its something I can help with and I can code an example, I will.

Comment: May I know where r u from? Just asking...Even I try to help too but some random guys downvote your question just for nothing. This is the case that if one has enough rep to downvote, will he be still eligible to do that...But still, you seem responsible. hope anything you are developing will get huge success. Thank you

Comment: I hope so as well. Working on a pretty large project. Im in the states. East coast. @LalitSinghFauzdar

Comment: It's my first project and it's too a large project but Until I have the support of this website and developers like you, I'll get pure success....

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar Don't rely on other developers to help. It's not our job to help people....we choose to. A community like StackOverflow is here to help, but maybe its best to search here before you post. A lot of the times is answered.... The hardest part is taking what is answered and making it work with your project.... but thats why were developers...

Comment: It's not about relying on someone...I was just giving a compliment to this community...It's the stachexchange group who made developing a project easier.....I don't rely on anyone...it was to promote the community....You'll agree on this that this website is useful...

Comment: Thanks for this line alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));