# How can I make an EditText in a ContextMenu

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView of values and I want to make each value editable by pressing on it and opening a context menu. How can I add an EditText field to the context menu that appears when clicking on an item in a ListView? If you have a better idea for said issue, feel free to suggest it. Thanks in advance to anyone who answers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a context menu for that. You can use AlertDialog. 
Check out this answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45352961/8200290

Just create a different layout with an edit view.

Here is you solution.

You are going to have to edit things to make it fit into your application!

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list.add("Android");
        list.add("iPhone");
        list.add("Windows");
        list.add("Blackberry");
        list.add("Mac");
        list.add("Laptop");
        list.add("LCD");
        list.add("Dell");

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_view_item, list);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked: " + list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View alertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, null);


                //Set the view
                alert.setView(alertView);
                //Show alert
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.show();
                //Can not close the alert by touching outside.
                alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

                //Set the edit text for the item clicked
                EditText editText = (EditText) alertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                editText.setText(list.get(position));

                ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) alertView.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);

                closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vzw.www.listviewalert.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

custom_alert.xml

-> This will show your EDIT text. The box at the bottom closes the alert

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alertContainer"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_alert_bg">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/rowOne">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:background="#cdcdcd" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

@drawable/custom_alert_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

You get the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't want to make an alertdialog with a listview inside it, I want to make a listview that opens an alertdialog when one of the items is pressed.

Comment: it doesn't matter what I post, bud. I'm showing you how to create a custom AlertDialog. All you have to do is use this concept when you click on an item in the list. Just edit the layout for the Alert.... pretty simple stuff here.